# Woocommerce register form company field

Tags: forms, woocommerce

How do I make company field not required on the woocommerce register form. I edited some of theme code to make the field not required, but every time the theme gets updated it becomes a required field again

Comment: HI, do you mean to make the company name optional on the checkout page?

Comment: Yes, to make company name optional but on register form.

Comment: Did you try the code I put in the answer?

Comment: Yes I tried it Sallar

Comment: No it doesn’t work Sallar

Comment: Does your template have a child theme and activated?

Comment: Yes I got my child theme activated

Comment: please send login information to my email address sallarrabiei at gmail. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `child_theme` folder, you may find it in the following path `wp-content/themes/` inside the child theme you will find a `functions.php`
past the following lines in the `functions.php`

```
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['company']['required'] = false;

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_default_address_fields', 100, 1 );
```

More details are available in [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)